# Calculating SD for Change in time

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, meta-analysis, pre-post-comparison, standardized-mean-difference

I'm conducting a meta-analysis on weight change (T2 - T0) between Group 1 and Group 2. The data I have typically looks like this:

Weight (kg)
Group 1 (n=15)  |  Group 2 (n=14)
T0 65.31±16.49  |  59.06±18.40
T2 63.63±15.20  |  61.49±17.84

I can easily calculate mean weight change, but I'm struggling to calculate the standard deviation (SD) for this change. Considering the potential correlation between T0 and T2 measurements, how can I accurately calculate SD for weight change?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: You need to know the correlation.

Comment: What do you mean by that?
I need the r?
How would be possible to obtain that?
Is there any other way to approach that?

Comment: You would obtain the correlation by tracking individuals within the groups.

Answer (score 0):

The answer (with examples) is found here:

https://handbook-5-1.cochrane.org/chapter_16/16_1_3_2_imputing_standard_deviations_for_changes_from_baseline.htm

For the correlation, we typically assume a rho of 0.5.
In the above link, you see that the correlation can be calculated from studies that report mean (SD) for the baseline, follow-up and mean change from baseline.

Comment: I would simply assume 0.5 for the correlation. The assumed value should be informed by substantive knowledge about the rank-order stability of the measurements over a given time frame.